# Using a foursquare Callback within an HTML5 Android application

Tags: android, html, api, cordova, foursquare

I am creating a mobile application for Android using HTML5 with PhoneGap and Eclipse. I want my application to be able to check-in, but I dont know how to return it to the application with the Callback URL.

Comment: What do you mean by checkin? and return to callback URL? Can you be more specific?

Comment: @Coder_sLaY Okay, this is the first step in my application - 1. User clicks "CHECK IN" 2. Redirects to Foursquare to login 3. User will choose venue to be checked in 4. Return to app.

Comment: Why dont you check out this http://code.google.com/p/foursquare-js-api/

Answer (score 1):

You'll either need to have the user authorize your app to check-in on their behalf (https://developer.foursquare.com/overview/auth) or send them to the foursquare app using the proper intent (https://developer.foursquare.com/resources/client). If sending them to the app, there's no way to send a "callback" to take them back to your html5 app though.